# Using auth0 as a multitenancy user management tool architectural question and auth0 SAML authentication for specific organization

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, auth0

We are using auth0 as our B2B user management tool in a multitenancy SaaS application,
for each tenant we have an organization on auth0 and a specific connection(of type auth0)
and we create each user for a specific organization on the organization connection.

right now we are using OAuth, getting our customers organization name from the subdomain of the request (lets say stackoverflow is the organization and the host is company.com -> path would be stackoverflow.company.com)
we are using an authentication service that takes the subdomain, convert it to org_id with auth0 API and redirects to our auth0 /authorize endpoint. Aftherwards we retrieve the access token and if its valid, we "confirm" that the session is okey and keep on working with this session. the access token becomes irrelevant at this point.

Our backend is spring-security based application.

we tried to use the SAML authentication because working with access token on a session-based backend seems a bit wierd but we noticed we cant use org_id there and we must use the “prompt organization” screen of auth0, which is bad for us because we dont want our customers to enter their customer name in a different screen.

so few questions on this topic:

1. should we do it using SAML?
2. is there any way to send org_id to auth0 with the SAMLRequest so we wont have to ask our customers to enter their organization name?
3. are we doing this the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you don't keep going with OAuth2 / OpenID, using Auth0 features to enrich access-tokens with all the security data you need (domain, tenant, organisation, etc.) in private-claims and a custom `jwtAuthenticationConverter` in spring security conf to build an Authentication instance exposing this private claims?